# Convexity of a set of real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let
\begin{array}{l}
Y:=\left\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})|\text{ Every eigenvalues of }A\text{ is real } \right\}
\end{array}and for $A\in Y$, we denote the eigenvalues of $A$ by $\lambda_1(A)\leq\cdots\leq\lambda_n(A)$. 
(E.g. if $n=5$ and the eigenpolynomial of $A\in Y$ is $(x-1)^2(x-2)(x-3)^2$, then $(\lambda_1(A),\cdots,\lambda_5(A))=(1,1,2,3,3)$. )

Then for $k=1,\cdots,n$, Is the subset
\begin{array}{l}
Y_k:=\left\{A\in Y\left|\sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_j(A)\geq0\right.\right\}
\end{array}
 of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ convex? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no, because the convex combination of two matrices with real spectra may not possess a real spectrum in the first place. For instance, every nontrivial convex combination of $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ and $A^T$ has a full set of purely imaginary eigenvalues.